# Add GitHub as a registration/login option

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, login

I'd like to link GitHub to my Stack Overflow account as another login option. Right now these are the only options:

[image: Add Credentials]

There have been a couple related posts on Meta, such as [Login with Github?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251670/login-with-github) (posted in 2014) and [Authenticate to Stack Exchange using GitHub](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129555/authenticate-to-stack-exchange-using-github) (from 2012). The reason given was "GitHub is not an OpenID provider".

That argument is rather weak, especially seeing as Google is no longer an OpenID provider and Facebook has never been one. Most developer-oriented communities and services offer GitHub as a login option, so it's really quite surprising to me that Stack Overflow doesn't offer this feature.

**Will Stack Overflow ever support GitHub as a login option, or is this something that's just not possible?**

---

**Update:** Someone brought up a valid concern: *Do you sincerely think there is anybody out there who can't authenticate with either Google, Facebook or OpenID?*

Well, I have both a Google and Facebook identity so that's not really the issue. I currently use my Google account but I would prefer not to be tied to that identity forever. I try to use the GitHub login strategy for any developer-oriented site.

The only other concern I can think of is: *This might confuse people registering for Stack Exchange sites unrelated to software*.

I agree that it wouldn't make much sense to offer a GitHub login strategy on non-technical SE sites like [Seasoned Advice](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/) or [Science Fiction and Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com). That being said, if you offer a login strategy for one SE site, you should offer it for the entire SE network (I personally have accounts for 20+ sites). I would suggest putting a GitHub button front and center on sites like Stack Overflow or Programmers, but add it to the "more options" menu instead on non-technical sites. Example:

[image: helpful depiction of a wonderful idea]

Furthermore, if the Stack Overflow team ever wants to integrate any services/features with GitHub, having GitHub authentication strategy *already in place* might help a lot.

Comment: I think it would be highly productive way. gIntegrating github, stackoverflow and career SE could be a highly useful "integrated package" for the customers.

Comment: I also think this would be highly useful.

Comment: Just wondering, but do you sincerely think there is anybody out there who can't authenticate with either Google, Facebook or OpenID? Because that sounds like a bit of a stretch to be honest~ Especially when thinking about just developers.

Comment: @DavidMulder - Its not about not being able to authenticate with those mechanisms, its that people don't want to.  I favor this feature request, this should be at the top of the list.  We are talking code here!  That to me makes the most sense...hello github and stackoverflow?  They should become one!

Comment: @JonH: Seriously though, logging in with Github makes a lot of sense on something like c9.io where you actually *use* that integration for something, but if all you need is just speeding up a registration process it's not about how much alike those services are but just how one can make that registration process as easy as possible for as many people as possible. The Google+Facebook options are perfect in that sense. Not saying adding Github is a bad idea, just sounds like super low prio to me due to the overlap~

Comment: @DavidMulder For me it would not so much be the overlap, but the idea that I would not want to login to personal accounts (google, facebook) on office computers where I do use SO and github.

Comment: As a programmer/Software architect who doesn't have a Facebook account and prefers to authenticate with GitHub whenever possible, I do support this option.

Comment: [Arqade already allows auth via Steam](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/signup), so special-casing auth for one site is already possible.

Comment: AOL? Really? +1 :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The GitHub PR was finally approved and merged!! I wrote about it in [this blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/11/announcing-support-for-github-authentication-in-stack-overflow/). Here are the key excerpts:

> We are always looking for ways to make it easier to be a part of the Stack Overflow community. One of the ways we make things easy is by offering the option to log in via other services, like Google or Facebook. As of today, we’re adding another option to log in – GitHub!
>
> What this means to you is that you can now sign in to Stack Overflow by choosing GitHub when logging in, just like you can do now with Google or Facebook.

Comment: Thanks for adding this Geoff - it does indeed make a world of sense, particularly now OpenID has gone and the alternatives are privacy-killers! 

Answer (score 16):

This seems to have been [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) recently: (GitHub says ~one month ago):

[image: "Add login with GutHub" button on the page where I can add new logins]