# remove Facebook login

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, facebook

I am sure most of you know that Facebook has a negative impact on society. Even Facebook themselves admitted to this. People like Shaun Parker [are tying to help us to move away from Facebook](https://qz.com/1126271/facebooks-founding-president-sean-parker-admitted-how-it-exploits-human-psychology/).

One of the many things that I have come to understand about Stack Overflow since joining this, is that it is **not** a social network. Hence if Facebook is the biggest social network out there and on the other hand you have a website that is trying to distance itself from that (or at least that's what it looks like), don't you think that's just being hypocritical ?

Also Facebook and Stack Overflow are like oranges and apples respectively. I really don't see why they can be be linked together.

I would really be happy and dopamine free if Facebook was removed from Stack Overflow.

Comment: Your feature-request is a _feature-removal_? Why would we want to remove features? If you do not want to use FB login, don't use it (I don't).

Comment: Once more, I recommend you you re-read [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375365/how-do-i-present-a-proposal-for-change-or-write-a-feature-request-for-stack-over) to try to present better feature-requests in the future. Good luck!

Comment: Hmm, social networking sure made this "I don't like x about what you do so I'll boycott all your business" approach get out of hand.  You can only really win this fight when you don't use the same techniques that made the platform notorious.  Make something better, that's what we try to do here.

Comment: At any rate, login options will not be removed just because you don't want to use Facebook anymore. *Just don't use Facebook*. You don't get to make that choice for everyone else however.

Answer (score 24):

That some people around the globe start to realize that there is no *for free* social media platform is a good thing. Your privacy is worth a lot of money.

But I don't think that the single use of one feature, namely authentication, of a service would count as being *linked* on all their features. On top of that, you're not forced by SE to use a Facebook login, you can use Google or a simple username/password with SE itself. We can only be sad that [OpenId](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307647/support-for-openid-ended-on-july-25-2018) was scrapped.

If anything, I would support adding more different major authentication providers (like [GitHub](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309883/add-github-as-a-registration-login-option) or [Microsoft Live (or whatever it is called nowadays)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295645/why-is-microsoft-openid-not-available-to-login-with) and not remove the login option for over [one million users](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/932268). Stack Overflow needs users to survive, become profitable and remain relevant.

While I personally don't endorse the Facebook platform, I don't see *using* its authentication service means SE is being *linked* to their core features. The login option can stay.

If you're concerned about Stack Exchange somehow abusing  and/or sending usage data back to third parties, I've found <s>no</s> evidence that this is done by Stack Exchange and I <s>doubt</s> know they do <s>given</s> despite the answer from Nick Craver (ex SE staff) about [how much data they store from you on account creation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/321531/158100) (spoiler: not much back then, welcome in 2024). The <s>only</s> concern should be <s>rogue</s> ads that leave Facebook tracking cookies or try other nasty stuff but [once they got noticed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/378655/578411)  their existence is <s>short lived</s> tolerated.

Use a decent ad-blocker.

Comment: It would be better if SO explained the consequences of the login choices more explicitly. That is, what does facebook login (and Google for that matter) actually do behind the scenes.

Comment: @James both do [Oauth2](https://oauth.net/2/), is there much else to explain?

Comment: Are there any privacy implications: persistent tracking, logging of your SO activities by facebook and feeding into profiling, data sharing, etc.

Comment: @James no, although I only have a reference for [Google](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/321531/158100) and this reassurance *We don't log the JSON response from these requests unless there's a really bad error that ends up in the error log*

Answer (score 1):

[image: No Facebook]

it seems like this is happening. No option to log in or sign up using facebook.

Comment: I ran into this too, but I thought it was just my work computer. Weirdly if I open a question and hit "Sign up with Facebook" or I sign in via any other Stack Exchange site, it works just fine.

Comment: I managed to get around it somehow, I think by going to a sister site.

Comment: This appears to have been a bug: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/427924/