# Log In with Facebook not showing up on some devices and/or browsers

Tags: bug, status-completed, login

I use "Login with Facebook" to access Stack Overflow, but the button no longer shows up on Mobile devices. I am using Safari on an iPhone:

[image]

The button still shows up on my Desktop devices and functions fine.

EDIT:
The button shows up on my Mac using Google Chrome, and ALSO shows up on my iPhone on Google Chrome, meaning my assumption of Mobile being the issue was wrong. Not sure of any other devices, but it appears to be happening for other devices/browsers as well based on other input here.

Comment: On desktop, I'm getting the Facebook login option in Firefox, but it's not visible for me in Chrome which is odd.

Comment: "The button still shows up on my Desktop devices". Which are...? Something is definitely wrong, and it's now clearly a lot broader than just mobile Safari.

Comment: There is currently an A/B experiment running that changes the sign-up flow for the next few days. Whether the option appears is not related to whether you're on the mobile or desktop view in your browser. But I will leave further details to someone more knowledgeable about the experiment.

Comment: @animuson oh, fascinating. Thanks for the update.

Comment: It's a bug which is an unintended result of the test mentioned - apologies all, fix is inbound

Comment: Should be sorted now, if somebody could check?

Comment: @cart looks fine to me

Comment: @cart OP here, works for me now on all devices I have. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This is definitely a bug (or they're trying to phase out FB login and did it very poorly), but there's an easy workaround (at least in some browsers):

- iOS Safari: You have to tap on the "AA" button next to the URL and then "Request Desktop Website".
- iOS Chrome: I had the *opposite* problem, strangely. Under the "..." (ellipsis menu), you need to "Request Mobile Site" instead as "Desktop" has the broken menu. Utterly baffling.
- Mac Safari:

  1. > If you can't see the "Develop" menu item, you need to enable it by opening "Preferences", "Advanced", and ticking "Show Develop menu in menu bar".
     > — [Flimm on SU](https://superuser.com/a/1292454/1254380)
  2. In the "Develop" menu item at the top, choose a mobile "User Agent" such as iPhone
- Desktop Chrome: Probably could be fixed with a user agent switcher extension, but I did not test this

Comment: Just FYI that there was [a comment by animuson](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427924/log-in-with-facebook-not-showing-up-on-some-devices-and-or-browsers#comment985428_427924) about A/B experiment several minutes after this answer was posted.

Comment: @AndrewT. And I almost felt bad for explaining how to bypass the test…except this isn't the "sign-**up** flow" but the "sign-**in** flow". I still think it's a bug that it's showing up on the login page too and preventing existing users from signing in.