# What does the new Google AI Partnership mean?

Tags: discussion, support, blog, overflow-ai

Context of the question: [Stack Overflow and Google Cloud Announce Strategic Partnership to Bring Generative AI to Millions of Developers](https://stackoverflow.co/company/press/archive/google-cloud-strategic-gen-ai-partnership) press release

---

> Stack Overflow has selected Google Cloud as the platform of choice to host and grow its public facing developer knowledge platform. In addition, Stack Overflow plans to leverage Google Cloud’s state-of-the-art AI capabilities to improve their community engagement experiences and content curation processes. The use of Google Cloud AI technology is expected to result in an accelerated content approval process and further optimized forum engagement experiences for Stack Overflow users.

I have several questions about this press release in general and this paragraph specifically:

- What does this mean?
- What can the community expect for "accelerated content approval"?
- What does "further optimized forum engagement experiences" mean and what should we be
  expecting?
- What should we be expecting when these AI capabilities are involved in the "content curation processes"?

Comment: I wish I could downvote that blog article to show my displeasure and disappointment that more time, manpower, and resources are being spent on AI that is absolute trash.

Comment: If only they could collaborate with Google to get half-decent search instead...

Comment: I have such a bad feeling about this announcement. I wonder if Google is getting some ownership of the company in all this?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk It's just riding the current "A.I." marketing racket. This claim is suspect on it's face _"to improve their community engagement experiences and content curation processes"_. On the one hand SO says don't post "A.I." generated answers, then wholesale farms out its "content curation" to "A.I.". You can't do both at the same time and be honest. Do as I say, not as I do.

Comment: Andy, since most of these questions need input from staff, I added the [meta-tag:Supoort] tag. But if you feel that's not appropriate (especially since it will make the question not eligible for hot meta), please feel free to revet. Cheers.

Comment: Given the claim this is ethical I'd like to understand the the increase in power consumption that's expected to deliver this partnership.

Comment: side note: "The first set of new integrations and capabilities between Stack Overflow and Gemini for Google Cloud will be available in the first half of 2024 and previewed at Google Cloud Next, April 9-11." [source](https://www.prosus.com/news-insights/group-updates/2024/icrier-2024)

Comment: It seems like currently nobody outside of the company (and Google) knows what that means. Maybe simply not enough information was given to even make an educated guess. Hopefully, it will become clearer in the future.

Comment: I didn't get Buzzword Bingo until quite far down in the blog post. Gonna have to adjust my bingo card. Wasn't even my strongest row that won :(

Comment: I don't even know what the word "community" means in the context of Stack Overflow. We keep saying it's a repository of knowledge, a wiki, a Q&A site. Absolutely not social media or a discussion forum. Yet we commune, apparently. I don't know when though, all actions you take on the site you do so without any kind of influence from other people - you do it in your own bubble and if we're lucky, you understood the gist of the site rules surrounding that one thing to be able to click the right button at the right time.

Comment: @Gimby _"Absolutely not social media"_ StackOverflow and all StackExchange Web sites are absolutely social media.

Comment: I guess this doesn't apply to StackOverflow management _"Reminder: Answers generated by artificial intelligence tools are not allowed on Stack Overflow. Learn more"_  Skynet and HAL are officially being ushered in on SO... Good luck folks!

Comment: Does it mean you [also got a letter from the FTC](https://www.wired.com/story/reddits-sale-user-data-ai-training-draws-ftc-investigation/)?

Answer (score 74):

> What does this mean?

I will only attempt to answer this question, because the others would really require staff input and anything I could say there would be *purely* speculative.

As far as I can tell, it means:

> Stack Exchange, Inc. plans to host Stack Overflow on Google Cloud. The company expects that this will cause Stack Overflow to grow, and that Google Cloud's AI technology can help users to curate content and feel more like they are part of a community. Specifically, the company hopes that this AI can help get new content approved faster and make users feel better about taking part in a forum.

It's not difficult to write plainly, but many companies seem to refuse to try.

Sooner or later, companies are going to be forced to understand that throwing around all these ten-dollar words doesn't actually impress technical audiences. Using this sort of deliberately opaque writing style tends to make intelligent people suspect that you have something to hide. This shouldn't be surprising, but apparently it is for some.

And in fact, it's evident that the company *is* hiding some things here:

1. Even more vague allusions to the idea the AI can fix everything, even though the userbase has repeatedly explained to the company both what is wrong with their ideas, and what has become clearly worse on the site as a result of AI's existence.
2. A supposition that the key difficulty with curation is that content *doesn't get approved quickly enough* - a baffling proposition; in reality, the main problem is that content doesn't get rejected quickly enough. There *can't possibly* be a problem with content being approved too slowly because *it starts in an approved state* (a misguided choice that is long overdue for correction, in my opinion). I don't know how to say it any more clearly: **the main problem with Stack Overflow is that the overwhelming majority of new proposed content does not meet standards and does not belong on the site**. This is a problem that cannot be solved by AI, because the problem is primarily caused by users (mostly but certainly not exclusively new users) ignoring the intended purpose of the site. (It seems that the staff also intends to ignore the intended purpose of the site.)
3. A supposition that Stack Overflow should be about "community engagement processes" and "forum engagement experiences". This should be immediately recognized as utterly absurd by any remotely rational person. One only needs to consider how many user accounts exist on the site to recognize the folly of this immediately; but on top of that it seems that the staff have forgotten that we [simply don't do that "forum" thing here, by design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107).

Comment: i somehow read right past the "hosting" sentence, maybe because i felt it needed no explanation? i dunno, :shrug:

Comment: _[...]  that throwing around all these ten-dollar words doesn't actually impress technical audiences._ It is not meant to impress technical audiences, it's meant to impress investors.

Comment: Theoretically, there are things that AI tooling could be used for to mitigate the problem with bad content. For example, if an algorithm could be trained to recognize the worst, obviously bad content (off topic stuff, resource requests etc), then that could be used to reduce the number of votes required to close said content. Reducing the cost of it. However that would go directly against the companies apparent goals of increasing the number of users at all costs.

Comment: @user1937198 *"However that would go directly against the companies apparent goals of increasing the number of users at all costs."* eh, not necessarily, it'd certainly be a less abrasive solution than the current one. It's far less painful to be told by the site that your question doesn't meet the standards of the network than it is for your peers to downvote and close the post once you've made it, which also pushes you toward a question ban. That's one solution i'd stand behind, provided it was accurate and doesn't result in only debugging questions.

Comment: The "what does it mean" is that SO could at some point use any of these products that are listed in Google page https://cloud.google.com/products/ai/ . There's one of those that there's a public facing example already "Generative AI Document Summarization"

Comment: The ten-dollar words weren't meant for technical audiences. It's a rare company that runs anything by its technical staff before signing a contract.

Comment: The announcement was likely written by AI...

Comment: One AI-ish package (that asked to remain anonymous) rewrote the text as this: "In a paradigm-shifting collaboration, a preeminent online forum has embarked on a strategic alliance with a ubiquitous cloud platform to shepherd its burgeoning knowledge repository. By harnessing the vanguard of artificial intelligence, this endeavor seeks to cultivate an optimized user experience, fostering synergistic community engagement and streamlined content curation processes." I hope that clears things up.

Comment: 2. and 3. tell us that SO intends to change in 2024 from being a curated Q&A site where dupe or bad questions are rejected, into a site where the preferred default is to accept nearly every submission, and quickly. As to "forum experiences", I take it they mean stuff like [Discussions](https://stackoverflow.co/labs/discussions/).

Answer (score 20):

I'm generally expecting the entire paragraph to be little more than marketspeak referring to the existing plans for the OverflowAI search/assistant feature. I can't comment on the current iteration of it, since it's a closed beta that I've yet to receive an invite to, but the [original showcase](https://youtu.be/DM9-cYyeaDg) of it that is still available on [/labs](https://stackoverflow.co/labs/) showcases the following features:

- Semantic Search that finds relevant answers and then passes those answers off to an LLM to be summarized,
- The semantic search results being presented as sources for the summarized text that can be voted on
- If the user then decides the summarized answer isn't applicable the assistant will then generate a question, potentially with some assistance to determine if it looks like a question that will be well received and the ability to directly post the question. (I'm expecting the "generate" step to not exist on the current iteration and the one launching likely in april.)

These in theory cover "leverage Google Cloud’s state-of-the-art AI capabilities to improve their community engagement experiences and content curation processes" in that it A: uses AI, B: supposedly improves the engagement experience of the user, and C: supposedly will result in less needed curation because it will reduce dupes/low quality questions.

They also can be argued to cover the second sentence, "The use of Google Cloud AI technology is expected to result in an accelerated content approval process and further optimized forum engagement experiences for Stack Overflow users.", in that content that has been deemed by the AI to be useful will need less approval, and "forum engagement experiences" is just someone not knowing the difference between Q&A and a forum and yet being responsible for Stack Overflow marketing copy.

---

Of course, it's entirely possible they're looking to implement an unwelcoming comment finder tool 2.0 as-well, or adding a hallucination generator in the ask wizard, reintroducing the formatting assistant, who knows. It's not like they haven't expressed interest in any of these in the past.

Comment: I imagined this would work more like facebook.stackoverflow.com did

Comment: I can't imagein they'd ever repeat that failure, certainly not in a way that'd draw people away from SO where they market all of their products. Yet, not all of their decisions make sense, so, ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score -5):

> What does this mean?

I can only say what it means to me: I am now greeted by a pop-up every day that wants to make me login with a Google account. I don't like it.

[image: screenshot of the login screen: "Use your Google Account to sign in to Stack Exchange" popup]

Comment: That's... Not something that happens to me. I can't reproduce that in any browser I have installed.

Comment: I am using Mozilla Firefox.

Comment: I've tried Chrome, FireFox, Opera, and even _*shudder*_ Edge...

Comment: Maybe you opted out of the cookies remembering your login. There was some cookie consent update thing maybe a month back and then one had to accept/decline once again. Not related to the Google-AI-something-something-partnership. See this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/386727/weve-added-a-necessary-cookies-only-option-to-the-cookie-consent-popup

Comment: @Lundin that doesn't give me a _google account login_ popup, though.

Comment: Well, all I can say is that it has started only recently. And it must be related to the site, because I don't get that with other sites.

Comment: It might be helpful to 1: submit a proper bug report (question) on Meta, instead of this answer here, and 2: Include screenshots of what you're seeing.

Comment: Not sure, but this might have something to do with an A/B test they were running with the sign-up flow. It wasn't announced but a [staff member had mentioned it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427924/log-in-with-facebook-not-showing-up-on-some-devices-and-or-browsers#comment985428_427924) in a post reporting a bug.

Comment: I just got this popup on another device, probably an A/B test since I didn't get it on both of them.